# what happens to its `value` attribute on ngModel?

Tags: angular, ngmodel

Why does `value` attribute does not work when we add `ngModel`. I understand now the `input` value is the one that is bind to `ngModel` but what happens to its `value` attribute? or to put my question in other way, why does `input` have value `20` (that is bind to `ngModel`) rather  than `10` (assigned to `value` attribute)

```
<input type="text" id="details" 
     [ngModel]="'20'" 
    value="10">
```

Comment: it is working, but it will be overridden by the `ngModel` value

Answer (score 2):

Look here https://angular.io/api/forms/DefaultValueAccessor. this is an implementation of value accessor that is applied for all `<input type=text` elements. As you can find it turns on when you apply for example ngModel to the element, as described in selectors section `input:not([type=checkbox])[ngModel]`.
Then if we look through the [sources of this value accessor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts), you can find that it overrides the value, when `writeValue` is triggered.

```
 /**
   * Sets the "value" property on the input element.
   * @nodoc
   */
  writeValue(value: any): void {
    const normalizedValue = value == null ? '' : value;
    this._renderer.setProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', normalizedValue);
  }
```